# why there is always a worker thread has no name in VS when debugging?

Tags: c#, .net

When I debug my application, I always see a worker thread who doesn't have a name like others:

[image]

You can see there is a worker thread id 17936, what does it do? What's the difference between ID and ManagedID?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/threading-model?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: ID is the real, operating system thread ID, the managed ID is the ID assigned by the runtime to (wait for it) managed threads, that is, threads running .NET code. Threads that have never run managed code have no name or managed ID. The exact details of which threads get created for what purpose varies a bit by runtime version and application framework used. If you turn on debugging unmanaged code and configure a symbol server, you can actually see what the thread is doing -- if it's a thread pool thread it won't be doing anything but waiting for work.